# NullPointerException SynthLabelUI

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a `NullPointerException` that I don't understand. Usually, the console points to a line in my code when this happens. This time, it's pointing to

```java
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLabelUI.getPreferredSize(SynthLabelUI.java:238)
```

which as far as I understand, is not in my code. Would someone please explain to me what's going on?

```java
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLabelUI.getPreferredSize(SynthLabelUI.java:238)
at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1660)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSliderUI.getHeightOfTallestLabel(BasicSliderUI.java:775)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthSliderUI.layout(SynthSliderUI.java:378)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthSliderUI.calculateGeometry(SynthSliderUI.java:343)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSliderUI$Handler.componentResized(BasicSliderUI.java:1496)
at java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Component.java:6331)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6285)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I'm painting custom labels with

```java
private void setSliderLabels() {
    Dictionary<Integer, JLabel> table = new Hashtable<Integer, JLabel>();
    table.put(-256, new JLabel("-w/2"));
    table.put(-128, new JLabel("-w/4"));
    table.put(0, new JLabel("0"));
    table.put(128, new JLabel("w/4"));
    table.put(256, new JLabel("w/2"));
    LSlider.setLabelTable(table);
    QSlider.setLabelTable(table);
}
```

Comment: Could you post minimal code that reproduce this situation?

Comment: What do you want to explain based?

Comment: Also, post the entire stacktrace.  It's likely pointing to a line somewhere in your code at some point.  Your code is just responsible for the SynthLabelUI crashing by handing it a null where it didn't expect or check for it.

Comment: Nathan, what you say sounds right. I'll post the entire stacktrace.

Comment: I think the exception is originating from my two JSliders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually means that you violated the (implied or expressed) contract of the API you are using. For example calling a method with a null value that is not supposed to be called with null, or not setting some fields that ought to be set. If the API is not clear in that regard, this is often guesswork.

Comment: This sounds congruent with Nathan's comment.

Comment: Setting the size of the JLabels fixed it.

Comment: private void setSliderLabels() {
        Dictionary<Integer, JLabel> table = new Hashtable<Integer, JLabel>();
        JLabel jlabel = new JLabel("-w/2");
        jlabel.setSize(20, 20);
        table.put(-256, jlabel);
        etc.